# Sum/Integral on function on random

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

What could be a general approach for researching the PDF's asymptotic of the following sum with $n\rightarrow\infty$:

> $$\sum_{i=0}^n f\Big(\sum_{j=0}^i\xi_j\Big)$$

where $\xi_i$ are independent random values with the same PDF (normal or 0/1 uniformly distributed) and $f$ is a non-trivial function - for example exponent?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first try to see if I could use the ["functional central limit theorem" (a.k.a. Donsker's theorem)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donsker%27s_theorem) to get any results for functions $f$ of interest to me.

Comment: Thanks, I know that but it is not directly applicable unless f is linear. I wonder if there are any papers around with the similar problem. That would be acceptable answer.

Comment: Well, if $f(x)=|x|^a$ for some fixed $a$, you can use Donsker to advantage.